# selecting first child img tag on hover CSS

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have the image fill the column with just a name and title over. Then on hover, the image fades out and a new text with info about the person fades in where the title was.. The columns should increase in size on hover as they do.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/motionair/pen/ExgRROy

I would be interested in javascript option, but i'm not that experienced in JS / CSS yet.

Here is my code so far, any tips greatly appreciated:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html,
.columnContainer {
  height: 80%;
}

.columnContainer {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.columnContainer>section {
  width: 15%;
  display: table-cell;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s linear;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

.columnContainer:hover>section:hover {
  width: 30%;
}

.columnContainer:hover>section:hover>img:first-child {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.columnContainer:hover>section {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:400px;">
  <div class="row columnContainer">
    <section id="1" class="col ">
      <div class="white">
        <div class="img d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img src="...." style="width: 70%;">
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: white;"> <span>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec maximus, mauris id tincidunt interdum, erat nisl eleifend lectus, quis pulvinar sem nunc non felis. Nam elit ligula, euismod a semper ut, convallis nec urna. Ut feugiat arcu quis justo efficitur, eu aliquet ipsum tempus. Fusce non ante eget quam malesuada hendrerit. Vivamus diam nulla, mollis id tincidunt ut, fermentum id ex.
              </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col">
      One of three columns
    </section>
    <section class="col">
      One of three columns
    </section>
    <section class="col">
      One of three columns
    </section>
    <section class="col">
      One of three columns
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
      #custom-grad {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #81bde0, #e1edf4);
      }
      
      .white {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      body,
      html,
      .columnContainer {
        height: 80%;
      }
      
      .columnContainer {
        display: table;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 90%;
      }
      
      .columnContainer > section {
        width: 15%;
        display: table-cell;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.5s linear;
        transition: width 0.5s linear;
      }
      
      .columnContainer:hover > section:hover {
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      .columnContainer:hover > section:hover > img:first-child {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
      
      .columnContainer:hover > section {
        width: 15%;
      }
      
      .columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(1) {
        background-color: rgba(200, 200, 250, 0.5);
      }
      
      .columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(2) {
        background-color: rgba(200, 250, 200, 0.5);
      }
      
      .columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(3) {
        background-color: rgba(250, 200, 200, 0.5);
      }
      
      .columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(4) {
        background-color: rgba(200, 225, 225, 0.5);
      }
      
      .columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(5) {
        background-color: rgba(225, 200, 225, 0.5);
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="custom-grad">

  <div style="height:400px;">
    <div class="row columnContainer">
      <section id="1" class="col ">
        <div class="white" onmouseover="mouseover();" onmouseout="mouseout();">
          <div class="img d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img id="img" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fuwosh.edu%2Fstudenthealth%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F26%2F2016%2F08%2Fanonymous-headshot.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width: 100%; height:100%; ">
            <p>Name</p>
            <p>Title</p>
          </div>
          <div id="text" style="background-color: white; display:none"> <span>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec maximus, mauris id tincidunt interdum, erat nisl eleifend lectus, quis pulvinar sem nunc non felis. Nam elit ligula, euismod a semper ut, convallis nec urna. Ut feugiat arcu quis justo efficitur, eu aliquet ipsum tempus. Fusce non ante eget quam malesuada hendrerit. Vivamus diam nulla, mollis id tincidunt ut, fermentum id ex.
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="col">
        One of three columns
      </section>
      <section class="col">
        One of three columns
      </section>
      <section class="col">
        One of three columns
      </section>
      <section class="col">
        One of three columns
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script>
    function mouseover() {
      var img = document.getElementById("img");
      img.style.display="none";
      var text=document.getElementById("text");
      text.style.display="block";
    }
    function mouseout() {
      var img = document.getElementById("img");
      img.style.display="block";
      var text=document.getElementById("text");
      text.style.display="none";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```